# Bash Command to Print All Apps Currently Running

Tags: macos, bash, applescript

What would be a command to print just the running apps (i.e. just the apps that show up on the dock). For example:

```
Chrome
Microsoft Word
Microsoft Outlook
Etc.
```

But **not**

```
Microsoft Helper App
Other helper apps not shown on the dock
```

Is there a tag to add to the `ps` command or is there an entirely different command to do this?

Comment: Though it's not a single command, you could parse that data from the plist file at *~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist*. Of-course, you'd need to convert it from binary to text format first.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: That won't work, unfortunately, because only apps _persistently_ visible in the Dock are represented in that file - it doesn't reflect currently running apps.

Comment: I could combine the 2.

Comment: @mklement0 Good point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: Turns out there's a **simple, robust solution using AppleScript**:

As a **one-liner**:

```
osascript -e 'set text item delimiters to "\n"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to (name of every application process whose background only is false) as string' | sort
```

More readable version:

```
osascript -e 'set text item delimiters to "\n"' \
  -e 'tell application "System Events" to ¬
  (name of every application process whose background only is false) as string' | sort
```

- `set text item delimiters to "\n"` tells AppleScript to separate list items with `\n` (a newline) when converting a list to a string.
- The heart of the `tell application "System Events" to ...` command, `name of every application process whose background only is false` returns a list of application processes from applications *not* designed to run in the background.

---

**Original, fragile answer:**

Unless you dig deeper than is possible with command-line utilities into individual running applications to determine whether they have a UI, you need to resort to *heuristics*, such as excluding matches with certain words in the filename (`helper`, ...) - which will never be fully robust.

Here's another stab at it, to complement [alvits' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786480/45375):

```
pgrep -fl '.*/Applications/.*\.app/Contents/' | 
  sed -E 's:^[0-9]+ .*/([^/]+)\.app[[:>:]].*$:\1:' | 
   grep -Evi 'helper|daemon|service|handler|settings' |
     sort -u
```

Comment: Adding `settings` to the list made it work quite well.

Comment: Works perfectly. Ty (but unfortunately this is only a small part of what I am doing).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try.

```
ps -c -o comm -p $(pgrep -u $USER -d, -f /Applications) | grep -Ev 'Helper|handler'
```

This will display the processes as you have posted.

The inner `$(pgrep -u $USER -d, -f /Application)` will print the `PID`s of the processes owned by user `$USER` delimited by comma.

The outer `ps` will print the processes identified by process id list in `-p ...`.

`-o comm` tells `ps` to only print the process names.

`-c` tells `ps` to exclude pathnames of the processes.

Or

```
ps -u $USER -o comm | grep /Applications | grep -Ev 'Helper|handler'
```

This will display the full path to the processes.

Comment: This is on the right path but I still get outputs like bash, java, and Microsoft Database Daemon, all of which are helper apps or processes.

Comment: I don't understand why `bash` will show up when the regex is `/Applications`.

Comment: @dsiegler19 - Did you remove `-f /Applications` from `pgrep`? Or maybe you replaced `-f /Applications` with `-f .`?

Comment: I'm running `El Capitan` upgraded from `Maverick - > Yosemite`. Maybe all your processes including `bash` resides in `/Applications`. In `El Capitan`, `bash` is not located in `/Applications`. Or maybe you are running a `homebrew`ed `bash`?

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.10, Yosemite. Also, I ran the command from iTerm.

Comment: @dsiegler19 - What does `ps -ef | grep bash` show? Does it contain `/Applications`? The next thing I can think is a bug in `pgrep` in Yosemite though a test in my Yosemite also worked. Can you also paste the output of `which pgrep`?

Comment: /usr/bin/pgrep was the output to `which pgrep` The output to `ps -ef | grep bash` was really lengthy and the only time it contained `/Applications` was when it was followed by NetBeans.

Comment: I have removed my answer as I did not see the `osx` tag. I apologize.